# scrollview works on emulator but not working on android device

Tags: android, scrollview

In my android app there one scroll view is present,second scroll view is present which is present in first scroll view.The first scroll view is for full screen and the Second scroll view holds text view in it.Now  in emulator it is working fine i.e.both scroll view works fine but when i deployed the app on device the second scroll view is not working.
The first scrollview is in xml but the second one is dynamically created.

Scroll view in emulator is not working smoothly..

thnx for any help

Comment: Show us some code you're using. It's impossible to diagnose a problems without having to see what your code is. Also, which minimum Android/API version are you targeting?

Comment: What Phonon said. Without seeing your code we're just taking shots in the dark as far as helping you debug it.

Comment: descriptScroll=new ScrollView(this);
txtDescription=new TextView(this); txtDescription.setText("some text");txtDescription.setPadding(15, 20, 5, 5);
      txtDescription.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      txtDescription.setTextSize(14);descriptScroll.addView(txtDescription,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,50);

Comment: Is there a difference in screen size/density between the emulator and the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not advice to use ListView inside ScrollViews, because scrolling should be processed by only one View. And maybe the same applies to ScrollView inside ScrollView also.
No workaround is provided by Google guys.
You can check these web-pages:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6552
http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2d1a4b8063b2d8f7

Answer (score 0):

I guess your emulator runs on pre 2.1 and device to 2.2 or higher. If so, then you are relying on faulty behaviour that was fixed in 2.2 . Again, it is advised by google to not to nest scrolling views

Comment: no both are 2.2 version if u r having link specifying what goolge is advied plz give to me.